# How to limit the number of events in jquery full calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery full calendar. i want to show large number of events in a day.

But by doing this all events are overlapped and it becomes unpredictable events.

In the week view situation becomes worst.

Please help me guys so that i can show the large number of events in a proper way in full calendar.

Thanks,
Rajbir

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have so far on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below configuration on your calendar to avoid event overlap:

```
slotEventOverlap: false
```

This works for me.