# Limit the number of events created per day in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am working with fullcalendar. I want to limit the number of events created per day to 4 in week's view. 
I have seen this link but it is not of much help
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678927/how-to-limit-the-number-of-events-in-jquery-full-calendar)
eventLimit options only limits the events displayed but I want to stop creating events once 6 events have been created per day in week's view.

Comment: what have you  tried

Comment: right now i am trying to count the events with a code that i found on stackoverflow
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
                    var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                    var countevents = 0;
                    if( allevents.length ) {
                        countevents = countevents + allevents.length;
                    }
                    if(!countevents) {
                        // alert('event count is'+countevents);
                        console.log('event count is',countevents);
                    }
                };

Comment: Where do you write your code to create events? Please provide more stuff that you have tried.

Comment: In my case there is interview.html file and this code is added in the same page with <script> tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after digging deep and learning more about fullcalender, here is how i did it. it was very easy i must say. `

```js
var event_count=0;// to count the number of events starting from zero
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
   editable: true,
   selectable: true,
   minTime: '09:00:00',
   maxTime: '18:00:00',
   columnFormat: 'dddd',
   eventLimit: true,
   select: function(start, end) {
     var eventData = {
      start: start,
      end: end
     };
    event_count+=1;//if the control is inside this function increment eventcount
    if(event_count<4){
                  //if the counter is less than four then do this
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
     }
   },
   eventClick: function(event){
    
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
      event_count-=event_count;//decrement event_count when event is removed
   },
   loading: function(bool) {
    $('#loading').toggle(bool);
   }
   
  });
  
  $('#view_calendar').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
  
});
  
 })
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
select: function( start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    var eventCounter = 0;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
        if (start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
            eventCounter++;
        }
    });
    if (eventCounter < 6) {
        // Code to create event
    }
}
```

This works for me locally.